# User level i18n using JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, internationalization

I have a web app using J2EE/JSF, JPA (Hibernate) and a MySQL database.

This web app enables users to enter strings of data about various entities and we now have a requirement to allow multiple languages.  The plan is to allow the user to enter in a base language, then repeat the process for each language they want to support. The data that is entered is serialised and downloaded by mobile apps, and the mobile apps should be able to request the data in a specific language, defaulting to the base language if their requested language is not available.

I'm looking for advice on how to implement the first half of this, i.e. how to store multiple language versions using Hibernate, with a minimum of faff / and a minimum of reduction in performance.  Happy to use OS libraries and plugins for Hibernate to prevent re-inventing the wheel.  Also happy if there's a simple solution that can be implemented using the stack I already have...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this on your own relatively easy without having to look for some framework. Just store your data items which needs to be translated in one entity toghether with the default value and referring that in a second entity which holds the translation for a specific iso code. A named query in the first entity could then provide you with a translation for a given key or the default translation.

Concering performance, it depends on the amount of data we speak of. If this is comparable to the typical message bundle of an application, you could justo load it into memory at startup and provide it to your application or if that is not feasable rely on the database index and entitymanager's cache to provide you with comparably fast access once the application warmed up a bit.